# how can I create a division between items in a listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-studio, interface

I'm working on android app that contains a list view of 4 or 5 items. similar to how gmail app displays emails http://pctechtips.org/data/unnamed.png
but I'm having difficulty separating the items with some visible line between them. like a border or something. What is the correct way to do this? Also what is the proper way of centering text vertically?
thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.george.droidnet.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hostname"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="IP Address"
        android:background="@color/primary_light"
        android:gravity="top|bottom"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connections"
        android:text="Connections"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_light"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DNS Queries"
        android:background="@color/primary_light"
        android:text="Ping"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Ping Host"
        android:background="@color/primary_light"
        android:text="Ping"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please search for how to add a divider to `ListView` or `LinearLayout`

Comment: there are many ways out there, for example add divider to listview or simply add Padding/Margin at bottom listview item

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.george.droidnet.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hostname"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="IP Address"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:gravity="top|bottom"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/connections"
    android:text="Connections"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DNS Queries"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:text="Ping"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Ping Host"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:text="Ping"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp" <!--  Set width of the line--> />
</LinearLayout>
```